# Issue building docker image containing prisma on mac M1

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, prisma

I have a docker image that contains prisma and runs on node16 alpine. The container mounts fine, but when I try to run either npm i or npm ci, I get this error :

```
bash-5.1# npm install

> prepare
> npm run prisma && ts-patch install -s 2>/dev/null || true


> prisma
> prisma generate --schema ./lib/database/myschema.prisma | prisma migrate dev --name init

Error: Unknown binaryTarget linux-arm64-openssl-undefined and no custom engine files were provided
Error: Unknown binaryTarget linux-arm64-openssl-undefined and no custom engine files were provided

up to date, audited 523 packages in 2s

65 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

I looked at different solutions online and tried to change my DockerFile , using node slim, changin apk to apt-get and adding openssl :

```
FROM node:16-slim as base
WORKDIR /home

ARG DATABASE_URL=postgresql://admin:admin@postgres:5432/sales

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bash \
  nano \
  curl \
  python3 \
  build-base \
  openssl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN npm set cache /home/.npm && \
    npm set progress false && \
    npm set unsafe-perm true && \
    npm set no-audit true && \
    npm set prefer-offline true

WORKDIR /home

ADD .npm .npm
ADD package.json .
ADD package-lock.json .

RUN npm ci --no-optional

ADD . .
RUN npm run build


########################################################################################################################

FROM node:16-slim as test
WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=base /home .

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]

########################################################################################################################

FROM node:16-slim as development

WORKDIR /home
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bash \
  nano \
  curl \
  python3 \
  build-base \
  openssl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN npm set cache /home/.npm && \
    npm set progress false && \
    npm set unsafe-perm true && \
    npm set no-audit true
COPY --from=base /home .

ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["shell"]

########################################################################################################################

FROM node:16-slim as prepare-production
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  bash \
  nano \
  curl \
  python3 \
  build-base \
  openssl \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN npm set cache /home/.npm && \
    npm set progress false && \
    npm set unsafe-perm true && \
    npm set no-audit true
RUN apt-get install -y openssl
WORKDIR /home
COPY --from=base /home .
RUN npm prune --production

########################################################################################################################

FROM node:16-slim as production
WORKDIR /home

COPY --from=prepare-production /home .


ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run"]
CMD ["start"]
```

I ran docker system prune and rebuild my image, it builds fine but I still get the same error about openSSL

How do I get those dependencies to install ?

Comment: Well, have you tried installing `openssl` ?

Comment: @JulienB. Yes, I tried to both install it manually and inside my DockerFile

Comment: And... it did not install? You got a new error message? You got the same error message...?

Comment: It does. I'm far from being an expert but it seems like it's there but won't run on ARM ?

Comment: It does what exactly?

Comment: @JulienB. The container mounts and launch fine. But when I run npm ci in the container bash I get the error above.

Comment: What's the value of binaryTargets in your prisma schema?

Comment: @NurulSundarani that was part of the issue (the other part, I must shamefully assume, was that when I changed my Dockerfile I was mounting my image after, I didn't know I was supposed to rebuild the image)

Comment: Just to confirm, this issue is resolved now, right?

Comment: Hi @JulienB. I'm new with Docker and I'm getting the same error:
Unknown binaryTarget linux-arm64-openssl-undefined and no custom engine files were provide
How do I install openssl?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your architecture arm64?